# no such file public/index.html in vercel deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

In my localhost it is all working `public/index.html` is working and it is rendering , but in the vercel it is crying that it is not able to find public/index.html

In my local machine:

```
async function readFileContent(filePath) {
    try {
        const response = await fs.readFile("public/index.html", "utf-8");
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error reading file ${filePath}:`, error);
        return "Error rendering file";
    }
}
```

[image]

In the vercel:

```
Error reading file public/index.html: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/index.html'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'public/index.html'
}
```

[image]

It is clearly there public/index.html liar vercel

My vercel.json config file

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{ "src": "server.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }],
    "routes": [{ "src": "/", "dest": "server.js" }]
}
```

Comment: Try `const response = await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/index.html"), "utf-8");`

Comment: @Konrad didn't work, did work around using the ESmodule version of the __dirname.
The problem is the present code which calls `public/index` is inside the utils, so it will search `...utils/public/index` which is wrong

Comment: public/index works in the localhost, dont know why not in the vercel environment